# How to combine sum and conditional count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has Id , ActivityDate and TotalSteps as column header. Please find dataframe details below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1844505072, 6847, '4/1/2016'], [1844505072, 5367, '4/2/2016'], [1844505072, 0, '4/3/2016'],[1844505072, 0, '4/4/2016']], columns=['Id', 'TotalSteps','ActivityDate'])


Id          TotalSteps  ActivityDate
1844505072  6847        4/1/2016
1844505072  5367        4/2/2016
1844505072  0           4/3/2016
1844505072  0           4/4/2016
```

Need to find the total steps taken by each id and also the count when total_steps = 0. In the above set , expected result is:

```
Id          TotalSteps    Zero_steps
1844505072  12214         3
```

Below code is written using pandas which gives two separate results. I want all results to be in a single dataframe.

```
df[df['Id']==1844505072].groupby('Id').agg(Sum_Tot_Steps=('TotalSteps','sum'))
df[df['Id']==1844505072].groupby('Id')['TotalSteps'].apply(lambda x:x[x==0].count())
```

Please provide any solution using python pandas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be convenient if you provide data sample in some other form or link to the data instead of image.

Comment: I'm not going to retype your data. Put it as text. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please, consider provide your data as Dict.  This way all community can focus just to provide you the best solution.

Comment: Why do you do `df[df['Id']==1844505072].groupby('Id')` but not just `df.groupby('Id')`?

Comment: I have edited my question to provide my data now

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes we can use just groupby, I was testing for a particular id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1844505072, 6847, '4/1/2016'], [1844505072, 5367, '4/2/2016'], [1844505072, 0, '4/3/2016'],[1844505072, 0, '4/4/2016']], columns=['Id', 'TotalSteps','ActivityDate'])
df.assign(Zero_steps = df.TotalSteps == 0).groupby('Id').sum()
```

Output:

```
            TotalSteps  Zero_steps
Id                                
1844505072       12214           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe here are the code you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": ["1844505070","1844505070","1844505070","1844505071","1844505071","1844505071","1844505072","1844505072","1844505072"],
    "DATE": ["4/1/2016","4/2/2016","4/3/2016","4/1/2016","4/2/2016","4/3/2016","4/1/2016","4/2/2016","4/3/2016"],
    "STEPS": [6832,0,1329,0,0,539,1432,3198,7233],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Create sample data which is df:

[image]

Statistics on the data

```
id_list = df["ID"].unique().tolist()
total_steps_list = []
zero_steps_list = []

for i in id_list:
    tmp_df = df[df["ID"] == i]
    total_steps_list.append(sum(tmp_df["STEPS"]))
    zero_steps_list.append(len(tmp_df[tmp_df["STEPS"] == 0]))

result = {
    "ID": id_list,
    "TOTAL_STEPS": total_steps_list,
    "ZERO_STEPS": zero_steps_list
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

And the result is df2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```py
df = df.groupby(by=['id']).agg({'step': ['sum', lambda x: x.count(0)]}).reset_index()
```

also you can use from this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['x'] = np.select([df.step == 0], [1], 0)
df = df.groupby(by=['id']).agg({'step': 'sum' , 'x': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
Total_steps = df.groupby('Id')['Steps'].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
Zero_steps =  df[df['Steps']==0].groupby('Id')['Steps'].count().reset_index(drop=True)
ID = df.groupby('Id')['Steps'].sum().index

data1 = {
    'Id':ID,
    'Total_steps':Total_steps,
    'Zero_steps':Zero_steps
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```